# How can I get the sidebar id on the current page?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

How can I get the sidebar id on the current page?

The question is simple. I have looked at [is_active_sidebar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar), [is_dynamic_sidebar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_dynamic_sidebar) but they don't provide the info that I need.

Comment: id of _which_ sidebar? There might be multiple sidebars on page. Or none.

Comment: of all of the sidebars on the page.

Comment: When and how do you want the sidebar IDs? Do you need them for PHP, JavaScript, CSS or something else? Do you need them before the page is rendered, during page rendering or after page render or something else? Do you need it on one page, on every page or something else?

Comment: I need it for PHP. I am using [is_active_widget()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_widget). It returns the sidebar id that the widget is in. I would like to check that sidebar id with all of the sidebar ids on the current page. The ultimate goal would be to only load CSS on those pages where the widget is active.